# error reportviewer

Tags: reportviewer

Hola a todos estoy en un proyecto winforms, en el cual debo usar `ReportViewer`, ya le agregué el rdcl, en el nuGet instalo `Microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.winforms`. 
Me voy a agregar nuevo elemento en el cuadro de herramientas y lo agrega, el problema es que cuando intento colocar el reportviewer me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ocasiones anteriores lo había hecho no me presentaba ningún problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Vete a la pestaña de nugets, y vete a la parte de comandos y escribe el siguiente comando:

```
install'package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms
```

Luego te vas a la pestaña de herramientas y le das click derecho en un espacio que este vacio de la caja de herramientas, le das a elegir elemento, te vas a la carpeta donde esta tu proyecto, luego vas a la carpeta que se llama `package\lib\n40` y dentro de esa carpeta te encontradas un `dll` con el mismo nombre del paquete que instalaste. Elige ese, luego ve a la pestaña y ya deberá de estar disponible.

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias